# not found activity to handle broadcast intent

Tags: android

This code isn't work. What happen?

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("a.b.c.d"));
        Intent it = new Intent("a.b.c.d");
        startActivity(it);
    }
    BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    };
}
```

ERROR:

```
01-22 10:55:21.812: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10405): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{sample.intent.broadcast/sample.intent.broadcast.Main}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=a.b.c.d }
```

Comment: Have you defined the activity in manifest file?

Comment: You are trying to start an activity named "a.b.c.d" this wont do anything. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? launch a different Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply trying to test the receiver, replace `startActivity(it)` with `sendBroadcast(it)`.

Answer (score 0):

a.b.c.d is not a registered intent. Use an activity that is exists. Check your manifest file or the list of intents of standard applications.